# how to intentionally not have same/equal heights with flex-wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Title says it all,
My list is supposed to be 2 columns because of the display flex and 50% width, but if one side is longer the other side will have a gap and that's what I'm trying to remove.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some Text Here</li>
  <li>Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here</li>
  <li>Some Text Here</li>
  <li>Some Text Here</li>
  <li>Some Text Here</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is not possible with flex row direction. Use column direction, or better CSS Columns: https://jsfiddle.net/q2pqxdjx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do it using flex like this, as they will all have same height by default (you may add border and you will see).

Instead you may consider using column like this :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  column-count: 2;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some Text Here</li>
  <li>Some Text Here</li>
  <li>Some Text Here</li>
  <li>Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here</li>
  <li>Some Text Here</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: alright, i took your advice. worked peachy! thanks!